# Degree of map on $U(n)$ and roots in $U(n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Recently I went to a talk of A.Thom in which he sketched a proof of the fact that the groups U(n) satisfy the Kervaire-Laudenbach conjecture.

At some point in the proof you have to argue that the map 
$f:U(n)\rightarrow U(n): u\mapsto u^s$ has degree $s^n$. ($s,n\in\mathbb{N}$) Here we view $U(n)$ as a differentiable manifold of dimension $n^2$ and the map $f$ is clearly differentiable. I have limited background in differential topology/geometry, but I think we need to show that for "most" elements $U\in U(n)$, we have to show that there are $s^n$ $s$-roots of $U$. I don't really see how to approach this problem, so hints, solutions or suggestions are very welcome.

It's however very easy to see that for diagonal matrices in $U(n)$ there are $s^n$ $s$-roots. Maybe this can help in some way.

Thanks

Comment: Oh wait, isn't just a consequence of the fact that we can write any unitary $U$ as $U=VDV^*$ where $D$ is diagonal and $V$ again unitary? Is it really that easy?

Comment: It isn't that easy, however it suffices to notice that it works for diagonal matrices and then invoke Sard's theorem. So it's easy, but in another way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : see the remark above :)